# meaning of the expression 順調に回る

Tags: words, expressions

I have found the sentence

> 勉強会が始まり、なんだかんだ順調に回り始めていた

that was translated as

> The study group seemed to have gotten off a good start

But I could not break down "順調に回り", could you explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third meaning of 回る according to jisho.org is *to function well*, and 始める is an auxiliary verb which means *to start*, so 回り始めた means *started functioning well*.

順調に is the adverb version of 順調, which means *favourable*, so something like *favourably*. If you put it all together, 順調に回り始めた is *started functioning well favourably*. It sounds redundant in English, but if we assume 回る is not as explicit as *to function well*, and the *well* is more implicit, the sentence makes sense, and the purpose of 順調に is to emphasize how well it goes.